# React Native - load content using "Navigation Experimental"

Tags: routes, react-native, reactive-programming, navigator

I did a Navigation Experimental with the React Native Tutorial and it's working! (on purpose)

My problem is: I can't load the "content" of the next scene... (Only the navigator change)

```
if (this.state.navigationState.index == 0) {
    const route = {key: 'secondepage', component:MyScene};
    console.log("après modification "+route.component.defaultProps.title);

    // Use the push reducer provided by NavigationStateUtils
    navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.push(navigationState, route);
}
```

The problem is I can't load the component "My scene"... 
I saw that I can get the props of the component Myscene (`route.component.defaultProps.title`) but it doesn't load the Text inside. Is `NavigationStateUtils.push(..,..)` working?

NB: If you want the full code, I can paste it. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ... It was working, just I hadn't change my function RendersScene...

(I add "switch (this.props.index)": so i can change the render with the index value (~which is the number of my page))